# Bootstrap: fix button width with fluid text width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

Using **Bootstrap 5**. I have a card to display brand info and button on right to navigate.

[image]

When the description content is short, the button looks good, in one line. But as the description length is increased, the button is broken in multiple lines

[image]

I want to have the button width in one-line only and width adjusted according to the inside content and the description content to be adjusted in the left over space.

Is it possible to achieve it using `flex`?

Codepen link https://codepen.io/anuj9196/pen/mdKjeEq

I tried setting fixed with to the button, but then the button size does not adjust according to it's inner content. Also tried putting `<br>` tab in the description content, but then on large screen, too much space is left blank.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add `flex-shrink:0;` to the Button. It will prevent it from shrinking at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following line of code to achieve this with flex:

```
//1. param flex-grow
//2. param flex-shrink 
//3. param flex-basis
flex: 0 0 auto;
```

This will calculate the basis by the length of the text, but won't grow or shrink if other items (description) change their size.